# Can i reduce the font size of iphone tableview header

Tags: iphone, fonts, header, size, tableview

I need to reduce the font size of the table view header. My string value is a little bit longer and it doesnot fit in to the header. so planning to reduce the size. Any one knows how to reduce the size, so that i can add the string to my table view header.

Thanks in advance,
Shibin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do you currently set the string in your table view's header?

I'd imagine you are setting your table's header view to a UILabel object:

```
UILabel *headerLabel = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 50)] autorelease];
headerLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize: 14];
headerLabel.text = @"Nice and Long Table View Header Label String";
tableView.tableHeaderView = headerLabel;
```

Can you just set the label's font as above?